# putting feet on the donkey!

Tags: meaning, idioms, translation

I'm translating the subtitle of a documentary about the artist "David Hockney" by B.B.C and someone says at about minute 9:

> "And he said this guy was just like this on his thing, and sort of
>   ***putting his feet up on the donkey***, you know, and all this"

There isn't any donkey anywhere. They are sitting in an school, someone is drawing and the other one is teasing him by inappropriate and rude gestures and attitude, and this sentence is about the way he is sitting in front of the other person.

I can't understand what is the meaning of "putting his feet up on the donkey"

It is talking about a rude person who is teasing someone and act rudely and it is describing his way of sitting and attitude. it should has something to do with the way of sitting.

can you please help me here?

Comment: Subtitles and transcriptions of videos are often difficult.  If you could link to the video, we might be able to assist in clarifying for you.

Answer (score 2):

*Welcome to Stack Exchange!*

> *putting his feet up on the donkey*

is **not** an expression in English.

I confirmed that fact with [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=putting%20his%20feet%20up%20on%20the%20donkey&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) (which counts all the words in every book Google has ever scanned, and charts the word frequency.)

However,

> *putting his feet up*

is a common expression.

> After a long day of work, it's nice to finally get home and put my feet up.

meaning:  rest, relax, perhaps lie down.

(Here's the [Google Ngram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=put%20*%20feet%20up%2Cputting%20*%20feet%20up&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cput%20%2A%20feet%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bput%20his%20feet%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20your%20feet%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20my%20feet%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20her%20feet%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20their%20feet%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20our%20feet%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20its%20feet%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20both%20feet%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20the%20feet%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bput%20me%20feet%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cputting%20%2A%20feet%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bputting%20his%20feet%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bputting%20her%20feet%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bputting%20your%20feet%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bputting%20their%20feet%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bputting%20my%20feet%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bputting%20our%20feet%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bputting%20the%20feet%20up%3B%2Cc0) for that phrase.)