# What is the meaning of ''this on his thing'' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> He said this guy was just like **this on his thing**

I didn't get what this sentence means. Can you explain it?

Kindest Regards!

Comment: Looks like it needs more context, since it doesn't make sense like that.

Comment: "His thing" might mean his penis, but you'd need to provide more context for that to be clear.

Comment: The structure is likely "like this" + "on his thing". Further explanation requires more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrasing here is very vague, and will be difficult to understand without context.  Taken exactly as written, the sentence has four parts:

> He said

We don't know who "he" is, but we know that he said what follows.

> ...this guy...

We identify the subject, but only with a vague reference.  This would only be clear through context.

> ...was just like this...

We identify the action the subject is taking.  There is probably an unspoken word here that is meant to be clear through context.  "Like this" is often a shortened form of "Acting like this" or "Responding like this".  It could also be a different action, "standing like this" or "surprised like this".  The shortened version is a very useful phrase, but assumes that we understand the speaker's intention.  Without context, there's little we can do to clarify that.

We also don't know what the speaker is referring to by "this".  We know that this describes the action being taken by the subject, but we don't know if the speaker is making faces, pointing to a subject, or otherwise communicating.  This phrase is meaningless without context.

> ...on his thing

Finally, we have the last vague statement.  Whatever action the subject was taking, it was happening on "his thing".  We don't know what "thing" is meant to replace here.  It could be as simple as "on his boat", or as complex as "on his scheduled September trip to Westchester".

So, we could rephrase the sentence like so:

> He said that *someone* ... *did something* ... *somewhere*

This is a phrase that leans heavily on context.  Out of context, there simply isn't any meaning here.

I did a search for this phrase, and the only other instances Google could find was another question on this page regarding a BBC documentary about David Hockney (re. [putting feet on the donkey!](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/147676/putting-feet-on-the-donkey))  If this is your source, we might be able to shed some light on it by reviewing the video clip.